# Flexslider and Right-To-Left language support

Tags: jquery, flexslider, right-to-left

I installed a template on WordPress that contains Flexslider. My language is written Right-To-Left (RTL). When the page is RTL, the Flexslider stops and no images appear. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 11):

flex slider doesn't support rtl languages. The only way to fix it is to make  the div holding the slider `direction: ltr`

1. On your theme, if the slider on the home page find a file called index.php find the div that's holding the slider and all this code  `style="direction:ltr;"` 
   this will display your articles on the slier perfectly
2. To fix text direction from rtl find a file called flexslider.css on your theme and on the line holding the code    `.flexslider .slides > li{` (line #25 for me) add this:
   `text-align:right;

     direction:rtl;`

These tow steps fixed it for me. Good luck

Answer (score 8):

fatma's answer doesn't work for me. What works is modifying the `.flex-viewport` by setting `direction: ltr`:

```
.flex-viewport { max-height: 2000px; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; -moz-transition: all 1s  ease; transition: all 1s ease; direction: ltr; }
```

Comment: Voila! fatma's answer didn't work for me either but this one does the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change both JS and CSS for it to work. Luckily it didn't require much work. I forked the project and added the support at https://github.com/layalk/FlexSlider/tree/rtl. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

To fix directional navigation, these rules in your own stylesheet should override flexslider rules:

```
/* Flexslider RTL */
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {background-position: 0 0; left: -36px; right: auto;}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {background-position: 100% 0; right: -36px; left: auto;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-next {left: 5px; right: auto;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-prev {right: 5px; left: auto;}
@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {opacity: 1; right: 0; left: auto;}
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {opacity: 1; left: 0; right: auto;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `reverse:true,` in `flexslider()` function and the slider worked in opposite direction than the default.

And

```
.flexslider .slides li{
    direction: ltr;
}
```

It worked for me.