# FlexSlider with direction RTL

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

Hi I am using flexslider for RTL website,in this case no images appear and I [should set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497255/flexslider-and-right-to-left-language-support) `direction` to `"ltr"` for a div that holding slider, and it solves my problem but in this case it makes my page horizontal scroll, 
[image]
how can solve this problem? 
below is my markup :

```
<div class="flexslider">

                        <ul class="slides">
                            <li data-thumb="/Content/slider/1.jpg">
                                <img src="/Content/slider/1.jpg">
                            </li>
                            <li data-thumb="/Content/slider/1.jpg">
                                <img src="/Content/slider/1.jpg">
                            </li>
                            <li data-thumb="/Content/slider/1.jpg">
                                <img src="/Content/slider/1.jpg">
                            </li>
                            <li data-thumb="/Content/slider/1.jpg">
                                <img src="/Content/slider/1.jpg">
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

and below is flexslider css :

```
/*
 * jQuery FlexSlider v2.0
 * http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/
 *
 * Copyright 2012 WooThemes
 * Free to use under the GPLv2 license.
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * Contributing author: Tyler Smith (@mbmufffin)
 */


/* Browser Resets */
.flex-container a:active,
.flexslider a:active,
.flex-container a:focus,
.flexslider a:focus  {outline: none;}
.slides,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;} 

/* FlexSlider Necessary Styles
*********************************/ 
.flexslider {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.flexslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;} /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
.flexslider .slides img {width: 100%; display: block;}
.flex-pauseplay span {text-transform: capitalize;}

/* Clearfix for the .slides element */
.slides:after {content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0;} 
html[xmlns] .slides {display: block;} 
* html .slides {height: 1%;}

/* No JavaScript Fallback */
/* If you are not using another script, such as Modernizr, make sure you
 * include js that eliminates this class on page load */
.no-js .slides > li:first-child {display: block;}


/* FlexSlider Default Theme
*********************************/
.flexslider {margin: 0 0 60px; background: #fff; border: 4px solid #fff; position: relative; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -o-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); zoom: 1;}
.flex-viewport {max-height: 2000px; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; -moz-transition: all 1s ease; transition: all 1s ease;}
.loading .flex-viewport {max-height: 300px;}
.flexslider .slides {zoom: 1;}

.carousel li {margin-right: 5px}


/* Direction Nav */
.flex-direction-nav {*height: 0;}
.flex-direction-nav a {width: 60px; height: 60px; margin: -20px 0 0; display: block; background: url(/Content/slider-nav.png) no-repeat 0 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; z-index: 10; cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px; opacity: 0; -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {background-position: 100% 0; right: -36px; }
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {left: -36px;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-next {opacity: 0.8; right: 15px;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-prev {opacity: 0.8; left: 15px;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-next:hover, .flexslider:hover .flex-prev:hover {opacity: 1;}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {opacity: .3!important; filter:alpha(opacity=30); cursor: default;}

/* Control Nav */
.flex-control-nav {width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: -40px; text-align: center;}
.flex-control-nav li {margin: 0 6px; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;}
.flex-control-paging li a {width: 11px; height: 11px; display: block; background: #666; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -o-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px; box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
.flex-control-paging li a:hover { background: #333; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); }
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active { background: #000; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); cursor: default; }

.flex-control-thumbs {margin: 5px 0 0; position: static; overflow: hidden;}
.flex-control-thumbs li {width: 25%; float: left; margin: 0;}
.flex-control-thumbs img {width: 100%; display: block; opacity: .7; cursor: pointer;}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {opacity: 1;}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {opacity: 1; cursor: default;}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {opacity: 1; left: 0;}
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {opacity: 1; right: 0;}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Is [this](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) the effect you want?

Comment: [this](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html) one is my effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution, I am using [bootstrp with RTL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap.RTL) support and it set `direction:rtl;` for `html` :

```
html{
  direction:rtl;

}
```

just commented direction property in above code and set `direction:"ltr";` for `sildes` wrapper:

```
.slides{
  direction:ltr;
  /*...*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this updated version of FlexSlider that has RTL support: https://github.com/layalk/FlexSlider

```
    $('#flexslider').flexslider({rtl:true});
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally i got solution with

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    reverse: false
});
```

To change the direction of english or arabic we can use.

If we need RTL then use it "reverse: true" or "reverse: false"

It works for me.. bestluck